# Rounding floats in Python

Tags: python, rounding

I have a large list of floats between 0 and 1 as seen below:

```
l1 = [0,0.2,0.9,0.75,0.3,1,0.43,0.65]
```

what i would like is to round these floats to the numbers:

```
l2 = [0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1]
```

Result here would be:

```
r = [0,0.25,1,0.75,0.5,1,0.5,0.75]
```

What i mean is for every item in `l1` choose the item that is closer to it from `l2` and replace with the latter. I could implement this using some for loops and check exhaustively but i was hoping for a slicker solution.

Is there a library in Python to achieve this elegantly?

Comment: Can the values in `l2` change or do you just want to round each number to the closest quarter?

Comment: Judging by the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12141150/from-list-of-integers-get-number-closest-to-a-given-value there doesn't seem to be a library that will do this

Comment: "for every item in l1 choose the item that is closer to it from l2 and replace with the latter" - are you strictly rounding up? Because `0.3` is closer to `0.25`, yet your expected output has `0.5`.

Comment: Depending on your real needs, this is a duplicate of either [From list of integers, get number closest to a given value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12141150/364696) (the distinction is immaterial for `int` vs. `float`) or [Python - Rounding by quarter-intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8118679/364696), so I've duped to those.

Comment: If you actually do want to round up, you can use NumPy: `np.digitize(l1, l2, right=True)`. But it's not clear if that's what you want, so I voted to close the question as "unclear" until you can clarify it. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Answer (score 2):

If `l2` is always `[0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1]` you can use numpy:

```
r = np.round(4*np.array(l1))/4
```

Output:

```
array([0.  , 0.25, 1.  , 0.75, 0.25, 1.  , 0.5 , 0.75])
```

If you want to only round up, use numpy.ceil:

```
r = np.ceil(4*np.array(l1))/4
```

Output:

```
array([0.  , 0.25, 1.  , 0.75, 0.5 , 1.  , 0.5 , 0.75])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using `round`:

```
l1 = [round(n*4)/4 for n in l1]
print(l1)
```

Ouput:

```
[0.0, 0.25, 1.0, 0.75, 0.25, 1.0, 0.5, 0.75]
```

Comment: According to OP, `0.3` should round to `0.5`, not `0.25`. It's not clear if that's a mistake or if they specifically want to round up.