Python function for rounding float down to nearest .25
I have a series of floats that I want to round down to the nearest .25 below the float. I need them to always round down. For instance, 1.80 and 1.99 both need to round down to 1.75. I have a simple function to complete true rounding:
def rounder(x,y = .25):
    return y * round(x/y)

I want to modify this function so that it always rounds down, not just to the nearest. TIA.

Just use floor division //:
def rounder(x, y=.25):
    return y * (x//y)

>>> rounder(1.48)
1.25


Maybe worth posting on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8118679/python-rounding-by-quarter-intervals and closing as dupe?
